# Feelings vs Mind

Tags: probability

This question should not be so difficult and probably can be too simple (but is asked just out of interest and because I argued with my friend).

Assume, we have a lottery that repeats two times (for example, now and a week later). The process consists of throwing a coin where head (1) is 'to win a lottery' and tail (0) is 'to loose a lottery'.

The friend states 'if I loose the lottery the first time, the chance to win next week is bigger'. Somehow, I am bit confused how to interpret this because from one side I think it is a right statement, from another side seems it is wrong.

1) From one side, if to consider getting at least one head in two "experiments", then the probability will be equal to 75% by:
$$
P(\{x_1=0,x_2=1\} \text{ } \vee \{x_1=1,x_2=0\} \text{ } \vee \{x_1=1,x_2=1\}) = 0.75
$$

2) From another side, he knows that he lost the lottery the first time (got 0). So, in this case I assume:
$$
P(x_2=1|x_1=0) = \frac{P(\{x_1=0,x_2=1\})}{P(x_1=0)} = \frac{0.25}{0.5} = 0.5
$$

Is there a mistake somewhere or it is right?
The confusion here is because I feel that 'if I loose the lottery the first time, the chance to win next week is bigger' seems to be true but seems it is not like that. Could you help to clarify it?

Comment: (1) appears to have no bearing on the question. Regardless, *both* calculations assume the chance of winning the second drawing of the lottery is $1/2$, no matter what happens in the first drawing. What more is there to say?

Comment: The key is to observe that: P(x2=1/x1=0)=P(x2=1) and hence the two events are independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! However, is that strange that usually we have this feeling in a normal life (that we lost first time and, that's why we expect that the chances to win the second time are bigger)? or there is something to say about it?